# How to include multiple folders in SMB share

Tags: network-shares, smb, shared-folders, windows-server-2012

I want to share multiple folders on SMB share (Windows Server 2012).

Is it possible to and if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear on what, exactly, you want to achieve. That said, you cannot have a share path point to two different folders at the same time. If you try to set that up, you will get an error message.

However, what you can do, is create a share path to the folder which contains the folders you want, thereby opening that folder when you go to the share path.